# Google Cloud Storage proxy through nginx to a private bucket

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to serve certain images hosted in one of my buckets in Google Cloud Storage. My application is hosted in a Compute Engine instance which also runs a Nginx server. When I try to access the image just by wget, the image properly downloads (I'm assuming this is because I setup the proper service account permissions through IAM roles). When I try to the same but through and Nginx `proxy_pass` directive, I get and access denied error on the web. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume you send auth token in your wget headers. So is your issue that you call the same wget command through proxy but headers are not properly propagated?

Comment: Afaik, I issued a plain wget request without any headers and my compute instance was already having the permission for that bucket through IAM role. Also in my bucket config, I don't see any credentials that I can use in the form of auth headers.

Comment: Can you please provide more info on how you request data? I assume that you make requests to storage.googleapis.com api, and if your bucket is private i don't see how this can be done without authorization. [Documentation example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object). May be you were using gsutil or client libraries?